# ASP.MVC Html helper to format text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

My string is:

```
 string title = "CaSiO&lt;sub&gt;3&lt;/sub&gt; perovskite in diamond indicates the recycling of oceanic crust into the lower mantle."
```

I used @Html.Raw(title) and got

```
CaSiO<sub>3</sub> perovskite in diamond indicates the recycling of oceanic crust into the lower mantle.
```

How do I print it in view as:

CaSiO<sub>3</sub> perovskite in diamond indicates the recycling of oceanic crust into the lower mantle.

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(title))` will display the string in the format you want.

(But why is the string defined in that way in the first place? Why not define it with `<sub></sub>` and then just use `@Html.Raw()` ?)

Comment: Thanks. It works. I am working with PubMed API, that's how they format some of the data unfortunately.